# Images Resizer for all iPhone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, image, app-store

I need to upload my application to App Store, I have some screenshots that I want to resize to different sizes to match requirement in App Store, is there any website/online tool that I can use for resize directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize Image from Mac no need to go anywhere.

Open Image in Preview And Then Select Tools and Select Adjust Size.

Check Screen shot Given Below.[image]